# How do websites change content that have already been labeled with very long expiry dates?

Tags: http, http-headers

What would happen if the server sets a very far away expiry date for a resource (e.g. 20 years later) and then after some new requirements emerge it decides that the resource must be changed? For example, the CSS files of some websites seem to have such long expiry dates. Is there another header that the website can send to cancel an exact previous cached resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once you have a very long expiry date, you have no idea if people will still be using that up until the expiry date.

The way to “change” something generally falls into two categories:

1. Create a unique filename so it’s versioned. For example styles.57ab85ca183.css instead of styles.css. Or perhaps styles.css?v=12345. This requires you to refer to the specific version in your code so does add a little complexity but there are tools for this.
2. Have a short expiry date. This is generally what people do with the main page (as it’s not possible to change that location with a versioned path).

Comment: Thanks, just wondering why not just use embedded ETags and control whether new content has to be passed or not from server side?

Comment: Because it’s slow. You need to make a call to the server for every request. For small resources it’s often as quick to re-downoad the whole resource as it is to check the status of it. Thus negating all benefits of caching.